# UWP show Fullscreen Popup, ContentDialog or Flyout

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, fullscreen

I need to display a full screen dialog (in application window boundaries) in my UWP application, but can't seems to make it work.  I tried with :

- ContentDialog only shows vertically stretched with FullSizeDesired="True"
- Popup, even trying to set the width and height in code behind its not working
- Flyout Placement="Full" only stretch it vertically just like the contentdialog

Can't believe I spend so much time on that thing :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
var c = Window.Current.Bounds;
var g = new Grid
{
    Width = c.Width,
    Height = c.Height,
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x20, 0, 0, 0)),
    Children =
    {
        new Rectangle
        {
            Width = 100,
            Height = 100,
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            StrokeThickness = 3
        }
    }
};
var p = new Popup
{
    HorizontalOffset = 0,
    VerticalOffset = 0,
    Width = c.Width,
    Height = c.Height,
    Child = g
};

p.IsOpen = true; // open when ready
```

You should see a semi-transparent overlay with a white rectangle in the middle of your screen.

Answer (score 1):

To make a popup Fullscreen I did the following. Hope this helps.

I have a user control I wanted to show as a popup. Its name "URLUserControl"

Step 1: UI of the UC (Just the first bit. Not complete code)

```
<UserControl>
<Grid>
    <Popup x:Name="MPopup" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
```

Step 2: UC constructor adds the following

```
private void InitURLUserControl()
    {
        MPopup.IsOpen = true;
        Window.Current.SizeChanged += Current_SizeChanged;
        MainGrid.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
        MainGrid.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
    }
```

Step 3:

```
private void Current_SizeChanged(object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainGrid.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
        MainGrid.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
    }
```

The above code will help the popup to be the center of the screen and display in fullscreen in size. Check it out. Happy coding!

Comment: Where is "myTranslate" used after this? It doesn't seem to translate anywhere

Comment: I have updated the code. You're correct. myTranslate does not require.